# Creating diff patch for all changes in a branch?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I created some branch (call it `brnch`) from `default` and made some commits there. Now there is a need to cherry-pick all diffs from the branch to some release branch for hotfix. Is something like that possible in mercurial?

```
    ^  ^ 
    |  |<--- brnch
    |  - commit3
    |  |
    |  - commit2
    -  |
    |  |
    |  - commit1
    -  |
    |  |
    |  |
    |--
    |
    -
 default
```

Is it possible to create a patch from all commmits in the branch `brnch` (commit1, commit2, commit3) and apply to some another branch (release hot-fix in my case)?

Answer (score 3):

See `hg help export` and `hg help import`.

Examples:

```
hg export branch(brnch) -o brnch.patch               # export everything on brnch
hg export -r commit1 -r commit2 -o cherrypick.patch  # cherrypick two changesets

hg update <somewhere_else>
hg import brnch.patch   # import the revisions in the patch

hg import --no-commit brnch.patch # import (but don't commit) revisions.
hg commit -m hotfix               # commit changes as one commit with "hotfix" description.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve that by means of `hg rebase`.

For simplicity I will assume that you want to see everything from commit1 onward in your *brnch* see put into your *release* branch. Thus checkout the *release* branch and then rebase your *brnch* commits:

```
hg update release
hg rebase --source commit1 --collapse --keep --dest . --message "bla bla something fixed"
```

Alternatively you can give a revision range. If the commits you want to see collapsed are non-linear in the *brnch* branch, then you will need to resort to graft (which is cherry-picking individual commits) - and you can collapse (`hg fold`) all grafted changesets subsequently in your release branch, provided you keep them initially in phase draft.